# Как в выпадающем меню сделать выборку ALL (по всем значениям)

Tags: javascript, функции, map, dropdown, value

Мне необходимо, чтобы помимо списка значений из базы данных было еще значение ALL т.е. выгрузить все значения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас данные подтягиваются из базы данных следующим образом

```
{{
    stores_data.data.map((stores)=> {
            return {
                label:`${stores.storename}`,
                value: `${stores.storename}`

            }
        }
    )
}}
```

Данные забираются из MySQL запроса stores_data:

```
SELECT * FROM stores 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT id FROM companies WHERE clientmail = {{appsmith.store.usermail}});
```

Подскажите как этом можно реализовать? Возможно нужно написать какой-то скрипт или как добавить в SQL ответ псевдоназвание ALL, чтобы если его выберут в дропдауне послать запрос на выборку всех товаров клиента ?

Answer (score 0):

Там где вы получаете ответ от БД, добавьте примерно следующее

```
stores_data.data.push({
    storename: 'ALL'
})
```

т.е. Вы в полученный список добавляете новое значение ALL. Если значение надо добавить в начало списка, то делаете:

```
stores_data.data.unshift({
    storename: 'ALL'
})
```

Далее уже стандартно рендерите данные. А уже при выборе ALL, скорее всего на бэке, обрабатываете это значение, как выбрать все, а не выбор по фильтру

Comment: Ок. Но, я не могу понять, как должен выглядеть код в итоге? 
 stores_data.data.push({
    label: 'ALL',
value: 'ALL'
})
А дальше как прикрепить в размапленное значение? 
.map((stores)=> {
            return {
                label:`${stores.storename}`,
                value: `${stores.storename}`

            }
        }
    )

Comment: @IndieDev Покажите ваш код, где вы получаете эти данные от сервера, тогда, можно будет дать более точный ответ, как должен выглядеть ваш код

Comment: я получаю его из MySQL запроса 
SELECT * FROM stores 
WHERE companyid = (SELECT id FROM companies WHERE clientmail = {{appsmith.store.usermail}});
он называется stores_data 
потом я его маплю. 
т.е. он показывает список магазинов клиента. и я их по одному вывожу в дропдауне
а теперь мне надо при выборе значения ALL показать весь список магазинов клиента целиком.

Comment: ![SQL запрос](https://prnt.sc/ThVVA-2IhZl3).

Comment: ![Место где идет маппинг](https://prnt.sc/M8ZM7ddyeCN_).

Comment: **Отредактируйте свой вопрос, что бы он отображал больше деталей**. Вы Привели только JS код по отображению данных. Если на пальцах: В список значений добавляете ALL, если он выбран, то на сервере проверяете значение и перестраиваете свой запрос на выбор всех значений.